# Can plural of human ever be humen?

Tags: plural-forms

*NB It's not a simple learning question. It's actually from my ORM software pluralizing entities' names unexpectedly. For curious and/or programming readers' reference, see [the source code].*

So, when I declare a class *Activity* and run my softie on it, it produces a statement to the database called *Activities*. Great, so we know it pluralizes. I can dig that. In fact it's kind of neat when we look into the schema later on.

Then, I created a class *Human* and the junky ORM mapper produced a statement called *Humen*. Is that just a faulty algorithm (since *Woman* and *Man* should be *Women* and *Men*)? It seems to be a bit far fetched.

Although there are a lot of [*man* suffixed words](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/man/), there **are** examples when the ending *man* originates from elsewhere (*roman*, *human* etc.) so generalizing the pluralization like so is very odd. Also, the developers **might** be using a different language altogether, where *man* means *donkey* and the plural of it is *hazaa*.

So my question is whether it's a viable pluralization (in English, that is).

Comment: Though I didn't downvote (yet), I don't think this question fits ELL, and perhaps it's better to be posted at a stack or a discussion forum that is specific to that ORM software. IMHO, the programmer (whoever wrote that piece of code) overlooked something.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for ELU.

Comment: I think english.stackexchange.com would be more suitable for this question.

Comment: Hi Konrad! The primary question can be answered by consulting a dictionary, and as such is off-topic for our site. If you have done so and still have questions, please describe what research you have performed, what you found, and what remaining question you have in light of such.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Although the origin of the question is in programming, I intend it to be linguistic one. I tried to provide a bit of background info (as to not get complaints about that). But the question can be seen this: "*Is there any way **humen** is the right plural form of **human**, although I myself never seen it before?*" I think it's wrong but being modest, I want to verify with the community. As such, I can't see how it's off-topic.

Comment: @Catija I believe ELU would suggest the exact opposite. Can't know for sure, of course. Basically, I want to make sure there's no way *humen* is in any way plural of *human* (not archaic, not slang not etc.).

Comment: @jim I see where you come from but unfortunately I haven't found a dictionary confirming this conjugation. I could conclude it's an incorrect form **but** I'm being modest, opening for me not finding it despite it being there (although not very commonly used). Perhaps I didn't ask the question obviously enough. Would you kindly take a look at the other comments I've replied with? Do you still feel it's off-topic? I can't say I agree on that.

Comment: That is exactly the purpose of ELU... To address the historical usage of words.

Comment: To answer your comment *[But is it in **any way** possible to be correct?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80273/can-plural-of-human-ever-be-humen#comment155333_80276)*: Define "correct." The concept of "correct' comes down to how a word is used, whether by one person, a group, some, many, most speakers. If you want to use *humen* instead of *humans*, feel free. No one else in the whole English speaking world may use *humen*, but why should that stop you? If a slang or non-standard usage doesn't exist at the moment, what is to stop your from starting one?

Comment: @GoDucks Of course, if we take it to the extreme, there might be a faction consisting of a single person who on Tuesdays between 07:46 and 08:13 uses that word. In this case I was looking for something more widely spread, yet not so canonical so it's familiar to me. I guess I got the answer indirectly.

Answer (score 5):

The plural of *human* is *humans*. *humen* may not be understood, and if it is understood will be widely perceived as wrong.

Comment: Perceived as wrong? Definitely. Hence the question. But is it **in any way** possible to be correct, if not intuitively obvious? A bit like using *sans* instead of *without*...